# Dapper.SimpleCRUD Insert issue without identity

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-simplecrud

I have table User

```
CREATE TABLE [User](
    [Id] [int] primary key NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EmailID] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

User class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

code

```
var usr=new User();
usr.Id=1;
usr.Username="jhon";
usr.EmailID="j@gmail.com";
_dbConnection.Insert<User>(usr);
```

The above code throwing null exception.Table with identity working fine.

Stack Trace:

> at Dapper.SimpleCRUD.Insert[TKey](IDbConnection
>   connection,      Object entityToInsert, IDbTransaction transaction,
>   Nullable`1 commandTimeout)

Error Message:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Dapper.SimpleCRUD.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Invalid return type

Comment: Are you sure `_dbConnection` is not null?

Comment: _dbConnection  not null

Comment: Assuming this is [this](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD), you might want to ask on the issues page there, to get visibility from the library author, too

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue today.  It's because you're specifying the type to be inserted instead of specifying the return type which would be int.  With that said however you don't even need to specify the type.

Your code can be simplified to:

```
var usr=new User();
usr.Id=1;
usr.Username="jhon";
usr.EmailID="j@gmail.com";
_dbConnection.Insert(usr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the correct answer from https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD

> [Required] - By default the [Key] property is not inserted as it is expected to be an autoincremented by the database. You can mark a property as a [Key] and [Required] if you want to specify the value yourself during the insert.

In my case, my primary key is a long / bigint:

```
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long MyPrimaryKey { get; set; }
```

And `T` in `Insert<T>` needs to match the return type (long):

```
connection.Insert<long>(model);
```